# Problems while upgrading the kernel in Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit to 3.2 version

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I run Ubuntu 10.04 on a 64 bit machine. I tried upgrading my kernel from 2.6.32-37-generic
to 3.2 version.

I downloaded the following files:

- linux-headers_all.deb
- linux-headers-generic_amd64
- linux-image-generic_amd64

Then I ran them using the following commands:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.0-030200_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_all.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.0-030200-generic_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_amd64.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.2.0-030200-generic_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_amd64.deb
```

But I got the following error:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-030200-generic (3.2.0-030200.201201042035) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-030200-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw for module r8169
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.2.0-030200.201201042035 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.2.0-030200.201201042035 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Running postinst hook script /usr/sbin/update-grub.
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-030200-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-030200-generic
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-37-generic
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-36-generic
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda2
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda4
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda4.  Check your device.map.
done
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-030200-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-030200-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/nvidia-common 3.2.0-030200-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-030200-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-030200-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-030200-generic
```

So how should I avoid this?

Please help me out.

Cheers,
Jayneil.

Answer (score 2):

3.2 is only for Ubuntu 12.04 at the moment. You must wait until the kernel-ppa team backports it to 10.04. This will be sometime in mid-May.
You should remove the kernel from synaptic.

If you want to add newer kernel for your lucid setup, try the kernel-ppa. The latest kernel is 3.0.0-15 (the oneiric kernel). It is backported to work on lucid. (The precise kernel will be here also after the release)

```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
```

And open synaptic and you will find the new kernel metapackage. (On my 32bit system: `linux-image-generic-lts-backport-oneiric` )

But if you really need the 3.2 kernel, upgrade your ubuntu to precise. It runs quite good on my test machines.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I followed your advice but got this error:W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/francisbrwn9/kernels/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve it..??

Comment: that is a personal repository, which you had previously added. Comment out the `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/francisbrwn9/ppa/ubuntu` line (add # to the beginning) in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and after that do a `sudo apt-get update`